# swift path to custom dir for images

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, dir

I have imagesDir in myproject dir

```
MyProject
---- MyProject
     ---- AppDelegate.swift
     ---- Main.storyboard
     ---- ImagesDir
          ---- images1.jpg
          ---- images2.jpg
```

How can retrive the correct path to "imagesDir"

Is a good idea to save in "imagesDir" the images saved by my application?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I don't think you need provide any path. Try `images1.jpg`. And you can open right bar to check original image path

Comment: thanks Maxim but i need the correct path to save image. Load image is ok ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS, you can't write data into NSBundle. Instead, write into document directory.

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0] as String
// documentsDirectory is your app's document path
```

Comment: thanks @scott work perfectly!. Is a good idea to save many images in documents directory or is there a better solution? For example make a subdir in documents directory .....

Answer (score 0):

You can get path like

let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("images1", ofType: "jpg")

Comment: thanks @Waseem the code is correct but i need the path of directory for save a new image >> let path = "PATH FOR imagesDIr"   imageData.writeToFile(path, atomically: true). Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Ok so you want to save image in document directory.

  var documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
  let filePath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingString("/images1.jpg")

Then write file at path.